# Getting the List from Sharepoint online using Rest Api in java

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest, office365apis

I want to use the REST API for getting the list as mentioned in [Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 REST endpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)

When I am trying to call `https://siteurl/_api/web/lists` in the rest client. I get the following error

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error
>   xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>-2147024891,
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code><m:message
>   xml:lang="en-US">Access denied. You do not have permission to perform
>   this action or access this resource.</m:message></m:error>`

Comment: please check this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165052/sharepoint-online-rest-api-get-list-selecting-all-fields-excluding-one or this:

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the REST services are only working for authenticated users. It doesn't work with anonymous access in 2013.

[SharePoint 2013 APIs for anonymous and/or mobile access](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47156/sharepoint-2013-apis-for-anonymous-and-or-mobile-access)

But You need to set the Bearer property in the request header with Authorization token. Please look into below mentioned code.

```
SharePointContextToken ContextToken = TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(ContextTokenString, Request.Url.Authority);

Uri sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);

//Get the AccessToken
String AccessToken = TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(ContextToken,sharepointUrl.Authority).AccessToken;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);

HttpWebResponse response =(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: May i know how do i get the AccessToken for calling sharepoint Rest Api in the java? please help me in this

Comment: Please look into it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804624/how-can-i-get-an-oauth-access-token-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0):

All request to the SharePoint REST API are made using the context of the current user. Since you are trying to call SharePoint REST API in your external java application, it is not able to authenticate the user thereby returning 403 Forbidden error. 
Please go through the below link on how to configure Basic authentication from Java to SharePoint
[BASIC authentication from JAVA to Sharepoint 2013 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570383/basic-authentication-from-java-to-sharepoint-2013-rest-api)